# Sending data using onSubmit from react to Node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I have this onSubmit in my React script which gets called when I click submit button:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
const form = event.target;
const rawdata = new FormData(form);
const data = {
    email: rawdata.get('email'),
    password: rawdata.get('password'),
};

console.log(data);
const response = fetch('http://localhost:4000/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
}).then(response => {
    if(response.ok) {
        console.log('Form data sent successfully');
    } else {
        console.error('Failed to send form data');
    }
}).catch (error => console.error(error));
}
```

which is supposed to send data to my node js script and calls the following function:

```
app.post("/register", function (req, res){
    console.log("inside /register");
    console.log("email: " + req.body.email);
    User.register({username: req.body.email}, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("couldn't register");
            //res.redirect("/signup");
        } else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                console.log("login granted");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But it says that the data I'm trying to log (req.body.email) is undefined. would appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have the line `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` anywhere in your code? Your `express` server needs it to properly parse and read the FormData sent from the client

Comment: Thanks @EvyatarShafran, Yeah I've used that already in my node js script, but still the data sent is undefined.

Comment: I think your problem might then be the `JSON.stringify(body)` line in the client...

Comment: Thanks @EvyatarShafran, I used body without stringify and still have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the code as follows and now I can get the data from react script in my node js script:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target;
    const rawdata = new FormData(form);
    const data = {
        email: rawdata.get('email'),
        password: rawdata.get('password'),
    };

    console.log(data);
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log("response ok: " + response.ok);
        console.log("response status: " + response.status);
        console.log("response json: " + response.json());
        if(response.ok) {
            console.log('Form data sent successfully');
            return response.json();
        } else {
            console.error('Failed to send form data');
        }
    }).catch (error => console.error(error));
```

and also in my node script I had to add the following lines in the beginning:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));
```

And now it works. the app.use lines in node was the issue.